# How to Post to a Google Plus user page from a python script using Google+ API

Tags: python, google-plus

I'm really confused with the process to create a post in a google plus page.

I have created a user in google plus and created a 'Page' (Business Page). Now, from a Python script i want to post to the 'Page'. So could you someone Suggest which API should i use ? Whether its Google + API Google Domain API?

I have done research and what i understood is that, its not possible to post to
a page from a script. or i'm i missing something?

I have already created a python script which can post content to facebook,Twitter and LinkedIn but stuck with Google Plus.

I have already gone through the links like

[Google + Domain API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/python)

[Google + API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation)

But those does not create posts directly in a page.

Please guide me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you had a look at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i want to post to page. I'm looking for something like posting to a facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the *Google Plus Pages api* (required for working with pages) is a separate api, and is not open to the public... You can send a request to join here:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup

I had the same problem...